# Upgraded eclipse now getting main.xml: NotFoundException: null - Saga continues

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I looked up on getting an emulator for a tablet and noticed a suggested that on checking for updates within eclipse , the latest SDK/ADT etc would provide this. At the moment I cannot check this because I am getting the following error on my main.xml file.

> error!
>   NotFoundException: null
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
>   The following classes could not be found:
>   - ToggleButton (Change to android.widget.ToggleButton, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

I have tried the three options it offers and on choosing edit XML nothing appears to show an error.

This project runs under Android 1.6 (wanted to make it as backward compatible as possible) and trying to cope with different screen sizes and orientations . At the moment I have the following layout folders:

```
layout(empty folder)
layout-large
layout-normal
layout-normal-land
layout-small
layout-xlarge
```

These all existing before the eclipse/android updates and I never had these errors. I searching the net on these , I read one suggestion of Project->clean (done this) and I then did Project->Build.

I also a suggestion to remove r.java so I have done this and ran clean and build. Still getting the same error. Oddly the code and the xml show no signs of errors apart from the above message appears at the bottom of the designer window for the XML.

The designer is set to 1.6 (API4) so it is not that the designer thinks I am on a different version to my project.

Update 1:

Since moving onto 2.1 - I found that although the layout does not show the error straight away, it then appears if I try and make any changes to it. Also I have updated the images and these do not appear to have changed either.

Update 2:

feco has suggested a reasonable suggestion of moving the build target to 2.1 as only a small percentage of users operate with a 1.6 handset now. I have decided to do this , it is more of a get around than a solution but it will have to do right now.

Comment: did you linked the the android libraries in Project Target?

Comment: Feco thank you for coming back to me. I checked the Build Path (if this is what you mean) and couldn't see anything wrong other than the Android 1.6 was not ticked so I ticked this and it still made no difference. I am running this on a Mac so the location of the settings could be different from a PC or Linux system.

Comment: I have checked the properties of the project and went into Android on the left section of the properties list, Android 1.6 is ticked in this list, are there other settings that I need to check?

Comment: Actually it looks like it has lost the ADT plugin as I have checked Help->Install New Software and there is nothing listed so I am going to try and put this back in

Comment: Right - found the existing ADT plugin and reinstall it all, however this has made no difference to this problem. I am running out of ideas other than completely removing eclipse Android SDK / ADT and start again. However I would prefer not to do this, also the same error is happening across all of my other working before projects so it must have something to do with the upgrade.

Comment: Further information, if I change the SDK/ADT visual designer from 1.6(API4) to 2.1 (API7) this error goes away. I cannot understand why as the application was created under 1.6. Now I am really confused.

Comment: I may have to start the projects again but before I do I think this may be fixed by using the NDK

Comment: Hi tim, sorry I was away, maybe you should change to the compatibility to > 2.1, cuz only the 0.7% uses 1.6 or below http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Feco - fair point I may have to do this, I wonder if android/Google are trying to stop 1.6 development then ? When I decided to start afresh with eclipse , and re-set it up , I found that trying to use 1.6 with a new project still seem to hit issues.

Comment: Unsure if my edit shows up as this still being an issue. Even after changing the build target to 2.1 and it appearing to work, once I changed anything in the layout - I get the same error as mentioned before

Comment: does you project have any sensitive data? do you mind sharing the project over a repo, so we can take a look?

Comment: Not really, is going to be a possible app (maybe free to start with) and is in its very early stages so a lot of it will look very rough around the edges as I ended up starting it again because I had begun it in 1.5 and then realised that 1.5 didn't handle different screen sizes. The code is not the issue, it is more to do with the layout(s) themselves. Do you really need to see the code? One part of the layout I have noticed is that the images that I have resized do not appear resized in the designer view but do appear correctly in the emulator of a phone

Comment: Something else I have remembered , if I try and use one of these layouts in a new project it does error as well

Comment: dont konw if this will help, try to set to java 1.6 on the project properties

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing from API4 to API10 (or more) in the "Graphical Layout" window -> upper menu -> Android logo (green robot) at the end